# React Router: state variable updated with setState not being passed down to Route correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

So, I have the following problem:
I want to allow users to set the language of my portfolio. To do so, I provide them with two links in the initial `<Language />` component, which set the state of `<App />` and then lead the user to the home screen - `<Home />`. The problem is, the updated `this.state.language` is not passed down to `<Home />`; instead, the initial value it had is passed down.

My code:

```
// <App /> component

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            language: "none"
        }
    }

    changeLanguage = event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        this.setState({ language: event.target.id }, () => {
            window.location.href = "/home"
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div id="app">
                    <Route
                        exact
                        path="/"
                        render={() => (
                            <Language changeLanguage={this.changeLanguage} />
                        )}
                    />
                    <Route
                        path="/home"
                        component={() => {
                            return <Home language={this.state.language} />
                        }}
                    />
                    <Route
                        path="/about"
                        render={() => {
                            return <About language={this.state.language} />
                        }}
                    />
                    <Route
                        path="/projects"
                        render={() => {
                            return <Projects language={this.state.language} />
                        }}
                    />
                    <Route
                        path="/contact"
                        render={() => {
                            return <Contact language={this.state.language} />
                        }}
                    />
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}

// <Language /> component

const Language = props => {
    return (
        <div id="language">
            <h1>Choose your language.</h1>
            <div className="lang-options">
                <a
                    href="/home"
                    className="lang-link"
                    id="pt_BR"
                    onClick={props.changeLanguage}
                    title="Português Brasileiro"
                >
                    <img
                        src="https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/myhostedfiles.raulf/Images/svg-icons/brazil-flag.svg"
                        alt="A bandeira brasileira. Clique para ter acesso ao site em português."
                    />
                </a>
                <a
                    href="/home"
                    className="lang-link"
                    id="en_US"
                    onClick={props.changeLanguage}
                    title="American English"
                >
                    <img
                        src="https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/myhostedfiles.raulf/Images/svg-icons/usa-flag.svg"
                        alt="The american flag. Click to access the site in english."
                    />
                </a>
            </div>
            <h1>Escolha seu idioma.</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

// <Home /> component

const Home = (props) => {
    console.log(props.language)
    return (
        <div id="home">
            <div className="bg-filter" />
            <Navbar />
            <TypedIntro />
            <LinkBox />
        </div>
    )
}
```

When the `<Home />` component is loaded, `console.log(props.language)` logs `none` to the console, which is the initial value `this.state.language` is set to. Can anybody explain to me why won't it update, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `window.location.href` is going to refresh the page. That will lose all your state. Change your `<a>` tags to use the react-router `<Link to="/home">` tag instead.

Here's a CodeSandbox to help illustrate what is going on:

[image: Edit yk1n96ynmz]

Comment: I was using `window.location.href` to try and prevent the browser from redirecting before setting the state, but it wasn't working anyway. Your solution worked perfectly! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried exploring [this](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-languages/tree/master/example) as a solution? You would have a file where you define your keys to each language and pass around an `i18n` object to access each key. This is an anti-pattern as you are trying to mutate state with multiple components.

Answer (score 0):

You were having issues because you were using `windows.location.href` it will refresh the app. And after that you will get a new instance of the app and you will lose the state of the app. And it was the reason you were getting initial state in console.

Change `windows.location.href` to `this.props.history.push()` but to do so you need to wrap `App` component with `withRouter` HOC from 'react-router-dom'. I have changed your code in some places check that out. And try to use `Link` tag instead of `a` tag.

```
import { BrowserRouter , Route,  withRouter} from "react-router-dom";
.....

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
          language: "none"
      }
  }

  changeLanguage = event => {
      event.preventDefault()
      // react-router passes "history" as props
      this.setState({ language: event.target.id }, () => this.props.history.push('/home'))
  }

  render() {
      return (

          <div id="app">
            <Route
              exact
              path="/"
              render={() => (
                  <Language changeLanguage={this.changeLanguage} />
              )}
            />
            <Route
              path="/home"
              component={() => {
                  return <Home language={this.state.language} />
              }}
            />            
           </div>
      )
  }
}

// wrapping App component with "withRouter" HOC
const RouterApp = withRouter(App)

// <NewApp /> Component
// you need to do this because component wrapped inside
// "withRouter" HOC must be inside "Router" component
const NewApp = () => {
 return <BrowserRouter>
        <RouterApp />
  </BrowserRouter>
}

// <Language/> Component
const Language = props => {
  return (
      <div id="language">
          <h1>Choose your language.</h1>
          <div className="lang-options">
              <p
                  className="lang-link"
                  id="pt_BR"
                  onClick={props.changeLanguage}
                  title="Português Brasileiro"
              >
                  Português
              </p>
              <p
                  className="lang-link"
                  id="en_US"
                  onClick={props.changeLanguage}
                  title="American English"
              >
                  American
              </p>
          </div>
          <h1>Escolha seu idioma.</h1>
      </div>
  )
}   

// <Home Component/>
const Home = (props) => {
  console.log(props.language)
  return (
      <div id="home">
          Home Component
          <p>Language: {props.language}</p>
      </div>
  )
}

// render NewApp component
ReactDOM.render(<NewApp />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: I was using `window.location.href` to try and prevent the browser from redirecting before setting the state, but it wasn't working. My problem has been solved by using `<Link />` components instead of `<a>` tags. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<Link to='/home'>` instead of window.location.href = "/home".

This will reload the page and reload the component. Also it disables react's capability as a SPA.